# My laptop isn't recognising my headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones, headset

My laptop doesn't recognize my headset. When I plug it in it asks me what audio device I plugged in, I choose headset then click OK. But no sound plays while it's plugged in and Playback Devices says that the headphones aren't plugged in.

I have installed the latest Audio driver from the Acer website and it doesn't help. Restarting the Audio Service and running the Audio Troubleshooter also doesn't work as it says no headset is plugged in.

It also fails to work with the Microsoft generic audio driver.

I'm using Windows 10 20H2 and Aspire A315-56

I ran the playing audio troubleshooter and got this error.

[image: playing audio troubleshooter results]

[image: acer laptop not recognizing my headphones]

Comment: Are the two audio services indicated in your screenshot running? Have you tried installing the Realtek application from the UWP has specified in that forum thread I linked to earlier?

Comment: Yes both services mentioned in the screenshot are running, `Windows Audio` and `Windows Audio End Point Builder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for help [on the Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/my-laptop-isnt-recognising-my-headphones/00fb451f-0bfe-4893-9997-b4602fe097cc) and got a solution.

Using Device Manager to scan for new hardware, automatically update drivers by searching the computer for updated drivers, and using Windows Update to look for updated drivers failed to help.

Using the hyperlinks provided by people on the Microsoft forum, the different methods mentioned failed to work for me. However it was suggested that I download software designed to find updates to installed drivers. I have 3 such software installed.

- Driver Booster
- Driver Talent-
- Driver Fix

Driver Booster found me some updated audio drivers but that didn't solve the problem. Driver Talent couldn't find me any updated audio drivers. Driver Fix found me 4 audio drivers and one of them solved the problem.

Out of the 4 audio drivers Driver Fix suggested, one installer failed to run giving a blank error message. Two were designed for other computer manufacturers (HP and Gigabyte) so it shouldn't be run on my (Acer) computer (one failed to install anything and the other one corrupted my audio driver so I had to use device manager to rollback the driver).

And another one was both an Intel and Realtek driver combined in one. In my case it was called **Audio_Realtek_10.29.0.4479_W10x64** or **Realtek Audio Effects Component 01/02/2020**. Although the file and driver identifies as Realtek in the file and folder name in Windows Explorer, it also contains files to do with Intel HD Audio Smart Sound Technology.

After installing this driver, my computer then started to recognise my headphones after I plugged it in. It looks like my computer manufacturer (Acer) is providing a faulty or outdated driver on their (Acer) website. I will contact them about this so they can update their website.

The problem is solved now. :)